# How to find tuple with different value in a list using scala?

Tags: scala

I have following list:

```
val list = List(("name1",20),("name2",20),("name1",30),("name2",30),
                ("name3",40),("name3",30),("name3",20))
```

I want following output:

```
List(("name3",40))
```

I tried following:

```
val distElements = list.map(_._2).distinct
list.groupBy(_._1).map{ case(k,v) => 
  val h = v.map(_._2)
  if(distElements.equals(h)) List.empty else distElements.diff(h)
  }.flatten
```

But this is not I am looking for.

Can anybody give answer/hint me to get expected output.

Comment: task is not clear. do yo need group by values ignoring keys?

Comment: `list.groupBy(_._2).filter(_._2.size == 1).map(_._2)`

Comment: @Vishwas Your question is unclear. I like __0's answer below if you're matching against just the right hand side. I like my answer if matching against both. Can elaborate on how you would like things filtered?

Comment: Which are the search criteria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand the question as looking for the element of the list whose `_2` (number) occurs only once.

```
val list = List(("name1",20),("name2",20),("name1",30),("name2",30),
                ("name3",40),("name3",30),("name3",20))
```

First you group by the `_2` element, which gives you a map whose keys are lists of all elements with the same `_2`:

```
val g = list.groupBy(_._2)      // Map[Int, List[(String, Int)]]
```

Now you can filter those entries that consists only of one element:

```
val opt = g.collectFirst {      // Option[(String, Int)]
  case (_, single :: Nil) => single
}
```

Or (if you are expecting possibly more than one distinct value)

```
val col = g.collect {           // Map[String, Int]
  case (_, single :: Nil) => single
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that you're looking to match against both the value of the left hand and the right hand at the same time while also preserving the type of collection you're looking at, a List. I would use `collect`:

```
val out = myList.collect{
  case item @ ("name3", 40) => item
}
```

which combines a `PartialFunction` with `filter` and `map` like qualities. In this case, it filters out any value for which the `PartialFunction` is not defined while mapping the values which match. Here, I've only allowed for a singular match.